# Tried plotting a catplot but got this error

Tags: python, seaborn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YWCx.png)

why am i getting this error?
code : sns.catplot(data = data, x = data['Type of property'],y=data['Price'])

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sns.catplot(x='Type of property', y='Price',data=data)
```